# Sending Outlook 2007 Meeting Request with HTML Body

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-addin, office-interop

I know that Outlook.ApointmentItem.Body only supports plain and rich text formats. But my requirement is to send the Appointment with a Html body. Currently I am saving the ApointmentItem as an ics file and attaching it to the e-mail. This works but the outcome that I am looking for is that it is received as a meeting request. I.e. I receive this e-mail I can see the body and have the option to respond to the meeting request. I tried forwarding the AppointmentItem as a vCal but that does not work either. I am I headed in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way of doing this is using system.mail.net and building your own ics. But Outlook and probably other mail clients will convert the html to rtf anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Go to new mail, Change it to HTML under Format text and on the same mail, put all your meeting participant and then select schedule a meeting (Once again, from same new mail)